# How to optimize images for printed documents

Tags: graphics, printing

I have some images which I saved as PNG, with resolution set to 300 DPI when exporting the images with Gimp. In the PDF generated with pdflatex, the quality is good.
Unfortunately, on paper the situation changes (80g paper).

Mainly two issues:

- many details get lost
- some colours change (e.g. bright green becomes dark green).

How can I preprocess the images to get similar results on paper like on screen?

[image: Image as given to pdflatex]

[image: Image as printed on paper]

Comment: Assuming the first image is the actual png file (and not processed  by the forum, it is actually only 640 pixels wide by 512 pixels high (setting different DPI does not by itself make a small picture into a higher res one. This pixel size will never print well at more than about 2 inches wide. Maybe send the actual image as an attachment somehow.